# $\phi^*\mu_y = \alpha \mu_x + \mu$ is due to Lebesgue Decomposition theorem?

Tags: proof-verification, banach-spaces

Notation: $X,Y$ are locally compact spaces with first countability. $C(X)$ denotes complex-valued continuous functions on $X.$

Let $\phi:C(X) \rightarrow C(Y)$ be a linear isomorphism and norm-increasing with $\|\phi\| < 2.$
Its adjoint is denoted as  $\phi^*:C(Y)^* \rightarrow C(X)^*.$

For any $x \in X,$ $\mu_x$ is a unit positive mass measure concentrated at $\{x\}$ only, that is, $\mu\{x \} =1$ and $\mu(X \setminus \{ x \}) = 0.$

In Cambern's paper entitled '[A Generalized Banach Stone Theorem,](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2035175)', he quoted the following in the beginning of the proof:

> Let $M$ be a real number with $\|\phi\| < 2M < 2,$ and let $M^{\prime} = \| \phi\| - M.$ For any $x \in X$ and $y \in Y,$ **$\phi^*\mu_y$ may be written uniquely as $\alpha \mu_x + \mu$ where $\alpha$ is a complex number and $\mu \in C(X)^*$ is such that $\mu(\{ x \}) = 0.$**

Question: How to obtain bolded statement, that is, which theorem guarantees that $\phi^*\mu_y$ can be written uniquely in the form given with properties stated above?

I think it has something to do with the [Lebesgue Decomposition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem), but I fail to relate it to the proof here.

Any guide would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\mu_x$?

Comment: @md2perpe: I have added the definition of $\mu_x.$

Comment: I don't think that we even need the Lebesgue Decomposition theorem. If $\nu$ is some measure, just let $\alpha = \nu(\{x\})$ and $\mu = \nu - \alpha \mu_x.$

Comment: How about uniqueness?

Comment: Suppose that $\nu = \alpha_1 \mu_{x} + \mu_1 = \alpha_2 \mu_{x} + \mu_2$. Then $\alpha_1 = \nu(\{x\}) = \alpha_2$ which implies that also $\mu_1 = \mu_2$.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like I have made my life tougher.

Comment: @md2perpe: By the way, just want to clarify, how to ensure that $\mu$ is a measure?

Comment: The space of measures is linear. It's given that $\nu$ is a measure and it's well-known that $\mu_x$ is a measure, so $\mu = \nu - \alpha \mu_x$ is a measure.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed this answer based on @md2perpe's comments above. All credits are to him.

For any $x\in x$ and $y \in Y,$ clearly $\phi^*\mu_y$ is a complex measure.

Let $\alpha = \phi^*\mu_y\{x\}$ be a complex number. Of course, it is zero if $\phi^*\mu_y = \mu_x.$ Otherwise, it is non-zero.

Let $\mu = \phi^*\mu_y - \alpha \cdot \mu_x.$ Observe that $\mu$ is a measure as it is a linear combination of measures. Clearly $\mu\{x\} = 0.$

We claim that $\phi^*\mu_y=\alpha\cdot \mu_x + \mu$ is unique.

Suppose that $\alpha \cdot \mu_x + \mu = \alpha^{\prime}\cdot \mu_x + \mu^{\prime}.$
Since $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ are fixed, we have $\alpha = \phi^*\mu_y\{x\} = \alpha^{\prime}.$ 
Evaluate the equation at $x^{\prime} \neq x,$ we have $\mu=\mu^{\prime}.$